# Deploying in Vercel got error: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.178.252.149:80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, next.js, vercel

My enviroment is here:

| Environment | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Rails | 7.0.0 |
| Axios | 0.26.1 |
| React | 18.0 |
| Next.js | 12.1.5 |
| AWS EC2 | Production |
| Nginx | Production |

I'm trying to deploy in Vercel for the fitst time.

Currently my next app works fine in local.

When I deploy in vercel I got the error:

```
info  - Collecting page data...
> Build error occurred
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.178.252.149:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
  type: 'Error',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    transformRequest: [ null ],
    transformResponse: [ null ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.26.1'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://mydomain/admin/users_data'
  },
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  status: null
}
Error: Command "next build" exited with 1
```

I'm using `SSG` and `ISR`.

The setting is here:

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const data = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/admin/users_data`
  );

  const paths = data.data.users.map((user: any) => {
    return { params: { id: user.id.toString() } };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (params: any) => {
  const data = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/admin/detail/${params.params.id}`
  );
  const user_id = data.data.user_id;
  return {
    props: { user_id },
    revalidate: 1800,
  };
};
```

I thought all the cause of bug is `cors`.

So I rewrote `cors.rb` which is from rails:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'http://localhost:3001', #client side is port 3001
            'https://staging-hoge-rails.vercel.app', # <-- here!

    resource '*',
             headers: :any,
             expose: %w[access-token expiry token-type uid client],
             methods: %i[get post put patch delete options head],
             credentials: true
  end
end
```

But still occurs that error...

I'm not sure vercel's origins is correct.

I refered this page in vercel dashboard.

[image]

What's lack to deploy?

Any advise will helps me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was cors problem.

I removed:

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const data = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/admin/users_data`
  );

  const paths = data.data.users.map((user: any) => {
    return { params: { id: user.id.toString() } };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (params: any) => {
  const data = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/admin/detail/${params.params.id}`
  );
  const user_id = data.data.user_id;
  return {
    props: { user_id },
    revalidate: 1800,
  };
};
```

for now.

Then build was though.

But it is not solution fundamentally.